# Retrieve check-ins of my friends from Facebook API

Tags: ios, facebook, latitude-longitude

Is there any way to retrieve the check in of my friends using the API for Facebook?
I am going to develop an iPhone app and I need latitude and longitude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is pretty easy to implement with Facebook. Check out the [Checkin api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/checkin/) documentation which which will give you the places the user and their friends have checked into, including latitude and longitude.  You just need to prompt the user for user_checkins permission.  This can also be queried using their FQL language, look at the [checkin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/checkin/) table. The latest [Facebook iOS SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk) & sample will help you get started making Graph API's quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Hii,

yes, you can retrieve checkins of your friends

```
-(void)getRecentCheckins {

NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   @"checkin",@"type",nil];



[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"search" andParams: params andDelegate:self];

 }
```

this will give a list of recent checkins made by your friends at request didload method.

Hope this Helps - for guidance use this Link:

http://tylerwhitedesign.com/how-to-check-in-using-the-facebook-ios-sdk-and-graph-api